# how to display json data dynamically in my listview in intel xdk

Tags: intel-xdk, jquery-mobile-listview

i am developing hybrid application by using intel xdk and jquery mobile framework for UI. i have json data, i am trying to display the json data in my listview but i don't know how to display json data in my listview

This is my json data

```
{

 "nl_wu":[
           {
              "id":"42",
              "year":"2015",
              "month":"jan",
              "title":"newsletter",
               "file":"http://school.com/sample.pdf"
            },

            {
               "id":"39",
               "year":"2015",
               "month":"jan",
               "title":"imagetest",
               "file":"http://school.com/sampleimage.jpg"
             }

           ]

}
```

i am trying to get above json data from URL by using this function

```
 function showsmsmessage(){
             var i;
             var out ="";
             var json;
             var arr ;
             var URL ="http://example.com/filename.php"; 
             var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhr.open("GET", "URL", false);
             xhr.onload = function(){
           if(xhr.status == 200)
            {
                var json_string = xhr.responseText;
                json = eval ("(" + json_string + ")");
                var s = JSON.stringify(json);
                arr = $.parseJSON(s);
                for(i=0;i<arr.nl_wu.length;i++)
                {
                     out = arr.nl_wu[i];
                     alert(out.title);
                }

             }
          else if(xhr.status == 404)
           {
             intel.xdk.notification.alert("Web Service Doesn't Exist", "Error");
           }
         else
          {
           intel.xdk.notification.alert("Unknown error occured while connecting to server", "Error");
          }
     }
       xhr.send(); 
}
```

i am getting "title" from json data by using above JavaScript function, i want to display this "title" in my listview in intel xdk, could you please tell me how this "title" in my listview

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190123/how-to-display-json-data-in-my-listview-in-intel-xdk

Answer (score 0):

As krisrak points out, there is code that answers the question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239006/3476918

But I should also point out that you should not be using eval for the purpose you're using it.  It's simpler and safer to use JSON.parse, i.e. instead of this:

```
var json_string = xhr.responseText;
json = eval ("(" + json_string + ")");
var s = JSON.stringify(json);
arr = $.parseJSON(s);
```

you should have this:

```
arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
```